# Rasp Pi 2: HDMI audio goes fuzzy temporarily

Tags: audio, hdmi

I have a Rasp Pi 2 connected to TV via HDMI. After watching video for about 10-15 minutes the sounds turns into a fuzzy mess, after 20 seconds it's back to normal like it never happened and I can't work out why this is happening?!

I'll try to get a recording of this but I never know exactly when it's going to happen. Essentially when watching a video the audio "fades" over a period of about 5 seconds into a fuzzy mess, it’s distorted beyond recognition (just a fuzzy hissy mess) for about 10 seconds, then over a period of about 5 seconds it "fades" back to normal (I can start to hear the words being spoken in the video as disturbances to the fuzzing noise, they become clearer and clearer until then eventually the audio is completely clean and normal again).

It happens on any video, it’s not a specific file or format. I’m stream media from NAS nearly everday and it happens on all kinds of video files (TV shows and movies). It didn’t used to happen which indicates I’ve changed something that has started this however all I’ve changed is the USB wifi dongle. I can’t see how that can be it? I've swapped the HDMI lead. No change.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: What software are you using to watch videos?

Comment: The Xbian version of Kodi - not at home right now, I'll get the exact version number when I'm home and I'll swap the wifi dongle back just for the sake of it